# How to calculate one day's uv every minute by SQL in Flink

Tags: sql, apache-flink, apache-calcite

We want to calculate one day's uv and show the result every minute by Flink.

We have implemented this by java code:

```
  dataStream.keyBy(dimension)
            .incrementWindow(Time.days(1), Time.minutes(1))
            .uv(userId)
```

The input data is big. So we use ValueState to store all the distinct userIds from 00:00:00 to last minute. For current minute, we union the minute's data with ValueState to obtain a new ValueState and output the current uv.

The problem is how to translate the java code to sql? We expect the sql to be like this:

```
   select incrementWindow_end, dimension, distinct(userId) from table group by incrementWindow(Time.days(1), Time.minutes(1)), dimension
```

Anyone can give me some suggestions? Thank you very much.

Comment: What are incrementWindow and uv?

Comment: IncrementWindow is defined by myself based on TumblingEventTimeWindows. For my case, the window size is 1 day and trigger interval is 1 minute. uv means the number of distinct userId.

Comment: Have you looked at https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/udfs.html#aggregation-functions ?